# Count the number of files in a folder using len() - odd result?

Tags: python

Newb here, so any help is appreciated.

I wrote a python script to search a specific folder for files and I would like to count the number of files. I then need to use the file names in the list as strings to search.

My problem is that when I try to count the number of files by the len(list), the script has been returning the same incorrect response: 34. I have added and removed files to the directory and have gotten the same response (34)

Is there something in my code that is causing the len(images) to be 34?

```
ubasepath= r'C:\User\brean\project'
for images in os.listdir(ubasepath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(ubasepath, images)):
        print(images)

NumImages = len(images)

print(NumImages)
```

## Code above returns:

```
modified-1 - Copy (2).png
modified-1 - Copy (3).png
modified-1 - Copy (4).png
modified-1 - Copy.png
modified-1.png
_buccal_JPG20191021212131+0000 - Copy.JPG
_buccal_JPG20191021212131+0000.JPG
34
```

The "modified-1.." to "_buccal..." are the 7 files contained in the folder. The 34 is NumImages

Comment: you're getting the length of `images` which is actually a loop variable...are you sure you want to do this? You are only getting the length of the final `image` in the loop.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a list here. Instead, that code is looping over the files and then printing the length of the last file name it sees. Try it like this instead:

```
file_list = []
ubasepath= r'C:\User\brean\project'
for image in os.listdir(ubasepath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(ubasepath, image)):
        file_list.append(image)

NumImages = len(file_list)

print(NumImages)
```

`file_list` is a list, and the loop is adding the filenames to `file_list`, which is what I believe you were intending originally.

Comment: Be careful, `l` is one of the variable names explicitly discouraged by PEP 8.

Comment: @AMC `Never use the characters 'l' (lowercase letter el), 'O' (uppercase letter oh), or 'I' (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable names.` well then. I have violated this many, many times... ok, good to know, i updated it, thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1):

`images` is your loop variable. at the end of the `for`-loop, it holds the last value in the iteration, in your case, that's `_buccal_JPG20191021212131+0000.JPG`. You then get the `len()` of that, but that only gives the length of that string (34).